# why update value use fields in uniq key rasie error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table  table1 (
  id  int,
  aid int,
  bid int,
  cid int,
primary key id,
unique key `u` (aid, bid)
)
```

```
1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2
```

I have a table and data like above,  but when I execute this SQL:

```
update table1 
set cid = 10 
where 
  aid=1 and bid=1
```

I get an error:

```
Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'u'
```

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.35

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual data in your table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  fake data,  i find that others do not got this error,looking for difference now

Comment: I don't think this error would occur with the two record table you showed us above.

Comment: Make select aid, bid from table1 group by aid, bid having count(*) > 1 results should be 0 rows

Comment: And check restrictions, cid = 10 should not be a problem